# How to see which UICollectionView Cells have been scrolled through

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView of posts. I want to be able to keep track of which posts the current user has viewed. How can I avoid certain issues such as quickly scrolling which wouldn't allow me to use did end decelerating.

The idea is to know all cells that have passed the users visible area of the screen. My collection cells are full screen.
Any ideas?

Comment: If a user quickly scrolled through your posts maybe its ok not to consider them viewed?

Comment: I think `UIScrollViewDelegate` would be the best. Don't use any timer as that would hurt the performance. Not sure why you think did end decelerating is not appropriate.

Comment: And use indexPathForVisibleItems

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `willDisplay` to track start time display cell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Save start time view at indexPath.
}
```

And use `didEndDisplaying` to track end time display cell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // End time at indexPath
    // End - Start time > "time of view" => Viewed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on a similar functionality, currentlyVisibleIndex holds the index value of the collectionView cell that has been viewed. For your implementation you can maintain an array having the index's of the cells which have been viewed

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>){
        /* set pagewidth to collectionview cell width*/
        let pageWidth = Float(collectionView.bounds.width)
        let currentOffset : Float = Float(scrollView.contentOffset.x)
        let targetOffset = Float(targetContentOffset.memory.x)
        var newTargetOffset : Float = 0.0

    if targetOffset > currentOffset {
        newTargetOffset = ceilf(currentOffset/(pageWidth)) * pageWidth
        /* if collectionview swipped right increment the curentlyVisibleIndex*/
        if currentlyVisibleIndex != (arrayOfModelForCollectionView.count - 1) {
            currentlyVisibleIndex += 1
        }
    }
    else{
        newTargetOffset = floorf(currentOffset/(pageWidth)) * pageWidth
        /*if collectionview swipped left decrement the currentlyVisibleCounter */
        if currentlyVisibleIndex !=  0 {
            currentlyVisibleIndex -= 1
        }
    }
    if newTargetOffset < 0{
        newTargetOffset = 0
    }else if  newTargetOffset > Float(scrollView.contentSize.width){
        newTargetOffset = Float(scrollView.contentSize.width)
    }
    targetContentOffset.memory.x = CGFloat(currentOffset)
    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(newTargetOffset), y: 0), animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `UICollectionViewCell`'s are full screen, what you can do is implement the `UIScrollView` delegate method, `scrollViewDidScroll` and calculate the cell currently visible. Something like this:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let index = scrollView.contentOffset.y/view.bounds.size.height
}
```

This will show whatever index is currently being displayed to the user. Since `scrollViewDidScroll` will always be called, you can use this method to determine the index user is currently at.